# How to update azure-cli on Windows?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

`az --version` is telling to update my CLI installation without explaining what to do.
So what is the `az` command to install the updates, if there is any? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I've tried looking for answers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest and here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/issues/1341 but can't seem to find anything related to updating it.

```
my-username@Azure:~$ az --versionazure-cli                         2.0.72 *
command-modules-nspkg               2.0.3
core                              2.0.72 *
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.3

Extensions:
interactive                        0.4.3

Python location '/opt/az/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/my-username/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Linux) 3.6.5 (default, Aug 22 2019, 06:32:32)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


You have 2 updates available. Consider updating your CLI installation.
```

I'm looking for something similar to `apt-get` command in Linux for installing, upgrading and cleaning packages.

Comment: Where do you want to upgrade the Azure CLI? Windows? Linux?

Comment: @CharlesXu Windows

Comment: I don't think you can find the command to upgrade the CLI, in Windows, you just need to download the new installer and install it.

Comment: `choco install azure-cli`, that is if you have choco

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli):

> The CLI provides an in-tool command to update to the latest version:

`az upgrade`

**However** the documentation notes:

> The az upgrade command was added in version 2.11.0 and will not work with versions prior to 2.11.0.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for back then. It's very nice and convenient now.

Answer (score 13):

based on what you've said:

> I'm looking for something similar to apt-get command in Linux for installing, upgrading and cleaning packages.

You could update **Azure CLI** with the help of [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). Chocolatey is a package manager for Windows (like apt-get but for Windows).

Once you have Chocolatey installed (I use it for most of my application installations on Windows), you can install the Azure CLI package that you want to update like this from the Command Line:

```
choco upgrade azure-cli
```

You end-up seeing an screen like this:

[image]

As you can see from the previous image I'm updating from version 2.0.45 in to version 2.8.0.
Once the installation is complete you should be able to see ii reflected:

```
az --version
azure-cli                          2.8.0

...

Your CLI is up-to-date.
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Check the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest#install-or-update

You can download a new installer from there and execute it to update your CLI version.

Comment: I've tried doing that and still getting this, ```You have 2 updates available. Consider updating your CLI installation.```

Comment: I ran the installer, updated, and now it says `Your CLI is up-to-date.` :\

Comment: I removed everything related to azure and then started fresh. It worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu / Linux try using the below inline script.

```
pip install --pre azure-cli --extra-index-url https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/edge
```

[image: az cli task in ADO release pipeline]